# Installing a letsencrypt Certificate on Centos

Tags: apache, ssl, centos

I am trying to understand the process of installing a [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate on Apache on Centos.

I have read the installation instructions, cloned the `git` repository, and there I’m stuck.

Has anybody had experience with this and what to do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really make it clear what your error was, but I'll take a guess and say that you left off with cloning the Git repository.

From here, you'll need to run some commands with the letsencrypt-auto program that you just cloned to actually obtain a certificate and install it. Let's Encrypt and their automatic configuration feature isn't necessarily stable yet, so I recommend running the command to only obtain a certificate, then manually configure SSL yourself. Head into the directory that you cloned the Git repository to and run the following commands:

```
chmod +x letsencrypt-auto
./letsencrypt-auto certonly
```

Let's Encrypt will begin to download its dependencies and a prompt will finally appear requesting which domains you want a certificate for. Just fill it in and press enter. If all goes well, you'll get an output that looks similar to this:

```
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem. Your
 cert will expire on 2016-03-08. To obtain a new version of the
 certificate in the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
```

This path will differ from my path since I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Note the path to the folder, which will hold all of the files you need. Now, head into your Apache configuration and edit the configuration file to link to the SSL certificates that you just created, restart Apache, and you should be good to go!

If you need any further instructions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn’t getting any error messages apart from Python 2.6 being experimental. It appears that was enough, and I have now tried with the --debug option (as per the message, but I didn’t understand the seriousness). I am now getting `InsecurePlatformWarning` and `DeprecationWarning` messages, but it did take me to the next stage. I will try installing the certificate manually. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have to check out some compatibility issues, but I found that, for my Centos installation, I need to do the following:
 `service httpd stop; ./letsencrypt-auto --debug certonly; service httpd start` (but on separate lines, since stopping `httpd` takes a moment to finish) 
and then manually set up the rest manually. Working well. Thanks for your help.